# Cisco VRRP Configuration: Can I use a /30 on VLAN Subinterface

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

I have been unable to find any documentation or examples where a /30 was used to configure a VRRP interface on a cisco router. Is this possible, if so does anybody have an example?

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1507
description CUSTOMER WAN
encapsulation dot1Q 1507
ip address X.X.X.X 255.255.255.252        // I don't have an extra IP
vrrp 150 address 10.102.32.210
vrrp 150 description VLAN 1507
vrrp 150 priority 150
vrrp 150 timers advertise 110
vrrp 150 timers learn
vrrp 150 track 100 decrement 60
vrrp 150 authentication text mypass
no shut
```

I understand this is the correct syntax, but obviously, when I have to use a /30 WAN I don't have an extra IP for the standby router's interface.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.77
description INTERNAL VLAN
encapsulation dot1Q 77 native
ip address 10.40.77.2 255.255.255.0         // 77.3 on Standby
vrrp 77 description VLAN 77
vrrp 77 ip 10.40.77.1
vrrp 77 priority 150
vrrp 77 timers advertise 110
vrrp 77 timers learn
vrrp 77 track 100 decrement 60
vrrp 77 authentication text mypass
no shut
```

Thank you in advance!

ADDING INTERFACE CONFIG

```
    redundancy
!
track 100 interface GigabitEthernet0/1 ip routing
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 no shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.75
    encapsulation dot1Q 75
    ip address 75.124.154.2 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 75 description VLAN 75
    vrrp 75 priority 150
    vrrp 75 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 75 timers learn
    vrrp 75 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 75 authentication text vrrp75!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.76
    encapsulation dot1Q 76
    ip address 75.124.154.6 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 76 description VLAN 76
    vrrp 76 priority 150
    vrrp 76 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 76 timers learn
    vrrp 76 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 76 authentication text vrrp76!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.104
    encapsulation dot1Q 104
    ip address 10.40.1.5 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 104 description VLAN 104
    vrrp 104 priority 150
    vrrp 104 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 104 timers learn
    vrrp 104 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 104 authentication text vrrp104!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.105
    descriptio
    encapsulation dot1Q 105
    ip address 10.40.1.9 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 105 description VLAN 105
    vrrp 105 priority 150
    vrrp 105 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 105 timers learn
    vrrp 105 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 105 authentication text vrrp105!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.149
    encapsulation dot1Q 149
    ip address 149.6.154.70 255.255.255.240
    vrrp 149 description VLAN 149
    vrrp 149 priority 150
    vrrp 149 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 149 timers learn
    vrrp 149 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 149 authentication text vrrp149!
    crypto map VPN_Tunnel
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.165
    encapsulation dot1Q 165
    ip address 165.42.149.206 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 165 description VLAN 165
    vrrp 165 priority 150
    vrrp 165 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 165 timers learn
    vrrp 165 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 165 authentication text vrrp165!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.166
    encapsulation dot1Q 166
    ip address 165.43.149.86 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 166 description VLAN 166
    vrrp 166 priority 150
    vrrp 166 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 166 timers learn
    vrrp 166 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 166 authentication text vrrp166!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.194
    encapsulation dot1Q 194
    ip address 209.198.218.1 255.255.255.128
    ip nat outside
    vrrp 194 description VLAN 194
    vrrp 194 priority 150
    vrrp 194 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 194 timers learn
    vrrp 194 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 194 authentication text vrrp194!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.1507
    encapsulation dot1Q 1507
    ip address 10.102.32.210 255.255.255.252
    vrrp 150 description VLAN 1507
    vrrp 150 priority 150
    vrrp 150 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 150 timers learn
    vrrp 150 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 150 authentication text vrrp150!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.2149
    encapsulation dot1Q 2149
    ip address 149.84.6.129 255.255.255.128
    vrrp 214 description VLAN 2149
    vrrp 214 priority 150
    vrrp 214 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 214 timers learn
    vrrp 214 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 214 authentication text vr!
    no shut
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 no shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1.77
    encapsulation dot1Q 77 native
    ip address 10.40.77.2 255.255.255.0
    ip nat inside
    vrrp 77 description VLAN 77
    vrrp 77 ip 10.40.77.1
    vrrp 77 priority 150
    vrrp 77 timers advertise 110
    vrrp 77 timers learn
    vrrp 77 track 100 decrement 60
    vrrp 77 authentication text vrrp77!
    no shut
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
```

Comment: Can you post complete config you want to try with dummy IPs?

Comment: @AbuZaid, Let me know if that helps.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet0/1.77

    encapsulation dot1Q 77 native

    ip address 10.40.77.2 255.255.255.0


If this is the interface, and on standby you are using 77.3, then it will work. You are using a /24 subnet mask for this interface.

Comment: That is not the problem interface, it is all my cross-connects to customers. the .252 interfaces are the one chirping about duplicate IPs and not working.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is not possible according to standards. You need to have a /29 subnet mask. Three IP addresses for two vrrp routers, and one for each client. It is answered in the following question.

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25171/vrrp-sharing-master-routers-ip

Now, some have tried a work around, by assigning secondary ip address for /30 subnet mask, but if you have the option to control remote side, then it defeats the purpose. You can just use a /29 mask instead. Here is a link for using secondary address.

https://lathiat.livejournal.com/36658.html

### Router1:

interface FastEthernet1/0
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
vrrp 1 ip 192.168.1.10
vrrp 1 ip 192.168.100.1 secondary
!
ip route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.252 FastEthernet1/0

### Router2:

interface FastEthernet1/0
ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
vrrp 1 ip 192.168.1.10
vrrp 1 ip 192.168.100.1 secondary
!
ip route 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.252 FastEthernet1/0